# Вывод из БД без перезагрузки

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как выводить записи из таблицы `БД` `MySQL` без перезагрузки страницы? Допустим если в `БД` добавилась новая строка, то мне ее выведет на страницу без перезагрузки. Скиньте хорошую статью где описывается реализация или может у вас есть простой пример чтобы посмотреть и понять хотя бы суть как это должно работать.

Comment: Это будет зависеть от многого, но так как вы привели PHP то вот один пример - http://socketo.me/docs/push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут есть 2 основных подхода:

1) polling - опрашивать сервер (например при помощи ajax) раз в промежуток времени и выводить новые записи из БД, если они там появились. Этот подход имеет ряд недостатков: 
- данные появляются не мнгновенно, а только при следующем опросе сервера
- большая нагрузка на сервер
- больше трафика от клиента
частично 2 последних недостатка можно уменьшить, если использовать заголовки кэширования HTTP

2) поддерживать постоянное соединение с сервером и со стороны сервера отправлять данные сразу после их добавления. Для этого можно использовать, например, websocket. Это решение несколько сложнее в реализации, но не имеет таких недостатков как у polling.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, насколько сложна реализация второго варианта и есть ли простые примеры чтобы для начала ознакомиться?

Comment: для PHP это не очень просто сделать из-за его специфики. Но если быстро погуглить то можно найти что-то вроде http://socketo.me/

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочий пример реализации `ajax` с помощью `jquery` файл `index.php`:

```
<?php

function is_ajax() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

if (is_ajax() && isset($_POST['get_data'])) {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8", 'root', 'PASSWORD');

    $pr = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `main` ");
    $pr->execute();
    $data=$pr->fetchAll();


    echo json_encode(array(
        'ok' => 'AJAX OK!!!',
        'data'=>$data
    ));
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <a id="get_data">Получить данные в браузер</a>

        <script>
            $("document").ready(function () {
                $("#get_data").click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var data = {"get_data":1};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "index.php",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (r) {
                            console.log(r);
                            // r будет содержать "ответ" из PHP 
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

С помощью `echo json_encode(array('ok' => 'AJAX OK!!!'));` мы отправляем ответ нашему браузеру и в панели разработчика можем увидеть ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно обратить внимание что пароли и важные данные принято передавать `post` методом.

Используйте например `PDO` для выборки своих данных из `mysql` или `oracle` :D затем вы получите массив и сможете отправить этот массив данных в браузер без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Суть в том, чтобы отправлять данные методами POST или GET (рекомендую POST) с помощью JS без перезагрузки и отлавливать это в PHP, а затем отправлять ответ в браузер.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но вопрос был чуть другой, вы отправляете данные в БД без перезагрузки, а ну нужно делать выборку без перезагрузки

Comment: я изменил пример. надеюсь что понятно. вот статья по AJAX. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp что касается PDO то есть много информации на php.net

Comment: С помощью echo json_encode(array('ok' => 'AJAX OK!!!')); мы отправляем ответ нашему браузеру и в панели разработчика можем увидеть ответ. Этот ответ может содержать массив данных, который затем можно использовать чтобы менять что либо в HTML используя просто `javascript` или `jquery. двумя строчками не обьяснить. вам нужно начать с подключения к БД чтобы понять суть. код который я представил это очень небольшой пример.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо больше, буду читать, пробовать, надеюсь все получится